# (wx)Maxima: return expressions using `sec` `csc` and `cot` instead of reciprocals?

Tags: output, trigonometry, maxima, wxmaxima

Currently, the output for inputs involving `sec` or the other reciprocal trig functions seem to return expressions in terms of reciprocals, e.g.:

```
expand(integrate(6*sec(2*y)^7*tan(2*y)^3, y));
>  1/(3*cos(2*y)^9)\-3/(7*cos(2*y)^7)
```

Is there any way to have this returned in terms of `sec(2*y)` instead? I checked the [documentation for display](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_9.html#Functions-and-Variables-for-Display) and the [documentation for trigonometric functions](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/docs/manual/maxima_54.html#Functions-and-Variables-for-Trigonometric) but didn't see anything that seemed to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `trigreduce` handles it (thanks to Stavros Macrakis for this info).

```
(%i2) 1/(3*cos(2*y)^9) - 3/(7*cos(2*y)^7);
                         1             3
(%o2)               ----------- - -----------
                         9             7
                    3 cos (2 y)   7 cos (2 y)
(%i3) trigreduce(%);
                        9             7
                     sec (2 y)   3 sec (2 y)
(%o3)                --------- - -----------
                         3            7
```